# Why does TypeScript allow (var && var <= 1) to return a type 'number | undefined' instead of a boolean?

Tags: typescript, types, boolean, operators

I have code similar to the example below:

```js
class HumanTail {
  private length_in_cm: number | undefined;

  private isTooShort(): boolean {
    return (this.length_in_cm && this.length_in_cm <= 15);
  }
}
```

Why does it produce the following error?

> Type 'number | boolean | undefined' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.

I believe that `(this.length_in_cm && this.length_in_cm <= 15)` should only return a boolean. How could it possibly return a number or undefined?

I know the workaround is to use `this.length_in_cm !== undefined && this.length_in_cm > 0 && this.length_in_cm <= 15`. However, I am curious as to why `(this.length_in_cm && this.length_in_cm <= 15)` could potentially return a number or undefined.

In PHP or Python, this expression returns a boolean value. Why does TypeScript return a different possible type?

Comment: If `length_in_cm` is `0`, `NaN`, or `undefined`, that value will be returned.